# How can I realize this design in layout android?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I need to achieve the following design for adding book in database.

[image]

I think using fragments and move from one to another one by clicking on the next button ,but for the step navigation it's just a imageView background or what exactly?

Comment: I think the best way, use custom recycleview.

Comment: Use another view in your activity above your fragment container

Comment: Please check update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Suggest some ways you may try..

you may use the same top bar and pass data with `SharedPreference` to the last Fragment, while you transition between fragments. (nested views)

or(Using layout_once.xml) make the content item's invisible until you get first item, so you make 2nd item's appear and first item's disappear.

Or for best solution use [stepper](https://github.com/stepstone-tech/android-material-stepper).

Comment: ok i will try the first suggestion, i think its the better solution in my case.